# Todos los valores de prueba con la API tienen los mismos valores aunque especifique otros

Tags: api, mercadopago

Estoy siguiendo el primer ejemplo que se da en la pagina https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/basic-checkout/receive-payments/ para la API de mercadopago, pero cuando pruebo usar otros valores (cambiando el precio, el titulo, etc) me manda a hacer una compra de un producto que siempre tiene el valor del ejemplo ($10) y que tiene por titulo ese "Multicolor kite" que tambien esta en el ejemplo.
Probe el enlace tanto del sandbox_init_point como el de init_point a secas, y en ambos casos pasa lo mismo.
Alguien tiene idea porque no toma otros valores?

Comment: Creo que deberías revisar un poco la implementacion que estas haciendo quizas no actualizas el preference_id correctamente, el comportamiento que mencionas no tiene mucho sentido ya que los valores de ejemplo es informacion ficticia creada para el developer site mas no tiene relacion directa con el funcionamiento del checkout.

Comment: Al final el problema es que no me percate de que tenia el codigo de las preferencias de ejemplo hardcodeado dentro del servicio donde genero la peticion a mercadopago, por lo que me pisaba los valores que definia dentro del controller (erch!)